# Facing issue in f.link_to_add in gem "nested_form"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

Hi I am using `gem "nested_form"` and in my view I have given like this

```
<%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task_form| %>
  <%= task_form.text_field :name %>
  <div class="star-rating" ></div>   
  <%= task_form.text_field :rate %>
<% end %>
<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a task", :tasks %></p>
```

In js file I have I have given this

```
$('.star-rating').raty({
    targetType : 'score',
    targetKeep : true

});
```

to show star rating I have used

```
gem 'jquery-raty-rails', github: 'bmc/jquery-raty-rails'
gem 'ratyrate'
```

so this add row but star rating is not shown I am attaching snapshot [image]

I have this type of design but when I click on `Add A Task` it does not render star-rating div it shows like this

[image]

I have included this in my js file

```
$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
  // this field was just inserted into your form
  var field = event.field; 
  // it's a jQuery object already! Now you can find date input
  var star = field.find('.star-rating');
  // and activate datepicker on it
  star.raty({
    targetType : 'score',
    targetKeep : true
    });
})
```

but still its not working.
Please guide how to render that div in nested-form.

Comment: Did you check if it is a Turbolinks problem?

Comment: How are you showing star rating? Through Javascript right?

Comment: read javascript events section from this doc https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form. You have to write a js callback function `'nested:fieldAdded'` and in that initalize raty for the new field

Comment: yes have modified myquestion please gothrough it

Comment: `<%= task_form.text_field :rate %>`  inside <div class="star-rating" >

Comment: I have tried this too but still star rating after click on button does not show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task_form| %>
  <%= task_form.text_field :name %>
  <div class="star-rating" ></div>   
  <%= task_form.text_field :rate %>
<% end %>
<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a task", :tasks, id:"add-fields" %></p>
```

And in your js file do:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-fields', function(){
   $('.star-rating').raty({
   targetType : 'score',
   targetKeep : true
  });
})
```

This may work for you.

Comment: Yes it works but its having an issue when I fill stars and then click on add-a-task then it empty my above filled stars

Comment: It is because there is same class so when you click on "ADD A TASK" then it add raty to all the div those have class "star-rating".You can set dynamic class name for this by using "<%= f.options[:child_index] %>" this will give you inxed value like 0,1,2,3...

Comment: @GauravGupta can u please explain how can we use that in the code ?

Comment: To add dynamic id  for 'div' we can do like this  <div id='<%="star-rating-#{ f.options[:child_index]}"%>' ></div>